# Camunda Rest API for process definition variables

Tags: camunda

I'm trying to fetch the process definition variables using Camunda REST API.
I'm using Camunda (camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter) 3.3.1 embedded in Spring boot application. (Camunda v7.11.0)

I've created a dummy process with a Start Event and form variables from different types:

- Date
- String
- Boolean
- Long
- Enum

When using the rest API *rest/process-definition/key/{processDefinitionId}/form-variables*, I'm getting the variables with incorrect types.

```json
    {
     "fromDate": {
        "type": "String", // Should be date
        "value": null,
        "valueInfo": {}
      },
      "to": {
        "type": "String", // Should be date
        "value": null,
        "valueInfo": {}
      },
      "renew": {
        "type": "Boolean", // Correct
        "value": null,
        "valueInfo": {}
      },
      "aLongVariable": {
        "type": "Long", // Correct
        "value": null,
        "valueInfo": {}
      },
      "department": {
        "type": "String", // Should be enum
        "value": null,
        "valueInfo": {}
      },
      "issuer": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": null,
        "valueInfo": {}
      }
    }
```